# How to keep the current state of values after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript. I developed a program where the user need to select all the values in the given controls, such as two combobox , two calendar, 3 textboxes. The user has to press the submit button after selecting all the values. I have given a "if" condition,where if user miss any values to select , it will give a alert message. The problem is if the user select one value and miss any other, it successfully showing the alert message , but the selected value is going back to old state after the refresh. How do I keep the current state even after the if condition occurs.

Comment: validate before submitting the form, if that's not enough, use `ajax` to submit the form and get a response

Comment: you can use localStorage for this.

Comment: What is causing the refresh? Please show your existing code.

Comment: after refresh means after clicking on alert's ok button  or processed after submit page??

Comment: What code you have got already? Have you made an attempt?

Comment: Try EnableViewState=True or EnableSessionState=True

Comment: can you put your code into jsfiddle>

Comment: if(fromvalue==="" || tovalue1===""){alert('Kindly select the origin and destination');}else if(infantcountvalue>adultcountvalue){alert("the infant number should be equal to or less thanadult");}elseif(departuredate==="" || returndate===""){alert('Kindly select the departure and return date');
}else if(departureday>returnday)
{alert('Return date should be after the departure date');}else if(totalpassenger>9){alert("Maximum 9 passengers are allowed.");
}else{window.open(StrQueryString);}

Comment: Please click [edit] and add the code directly in your question, don't put it in a comment. (But regarding the code in that comment, is it in a function, or...? What calls that code?)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the selected control values in Hidden variable and repopulate after refresh, But I am recommending here is -

1. Don't submit the form with validation error
2. Provide the server side validation if someone disable the JavaScript in browser.

Answer (score 0):

In onsubmit function, return 'false' when validation fails, after alert statement. This will stop the page from refreshing. 
As per my understanding from your code, the below should work:

```
form.onsubmit = function(){
     if(fromvalue==="" || tovalue1==="")
     {
        alert('Kindly select the origin and destination');
     }
     else if(infantcountvalue>adultcountvalue)
     {
         alert("the infant number should be equal to or less thanadult");
     }
     elseif(departuredate==="" || returndate==="")
     {
        alert('Kindly select the departure and return date');
     }
     else if(departureday>returnday)
     {
        alert('Return date should be after the departure date');
     }
     else if(totalpassenger>9)
     {
        alert("Maximum 9 passengers are allowed."); 
     }
     else
     {
        window.open(StrQueryString);
     } 
     return false;
     }
```

Comment: I tried this, but not working. Here is clear picture - One combobox is "from", another is "To". User need to select the values from both, if anyone miss, it will show the alert message. But after the alert message , its going back to old option in the combobox (select a value ) .